# What is the proper way of bundling in node dependencies with rollup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rollupjs

So I was trying to bundle in a bunch of external package dependencies using roll-up, like three JS and deck.gl. Right now I have a rollup config file set up like so, one to build just the code I have written and another that bundles in all the dependencies :

```
import externals from "rollup-plugin-node-externals";

export default [
  {
    input: "./Src/index.js",
    output: [
      {
        file: "./Build/pgl.js",
        format: "iife",
        plugins: [
          externals({
            deps: true, // Dependencies will not be bundled in
          }),
        ],
      },
      {
        file: "./Build/pgl_module.js",
        format: "iife",
        plugins: [
          externals({
            deps: false, // Dependencies will be bundled in
          }),
        ],
        sourceMap: true,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I have also tried to do the same thing with something like

```
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: {
    dir: 'output',
    format: 'cjs'
  },
  plugins: [nodeResolve()]
};
```

but to no avail it never bundles up the node packages into the build file and always gives the error :

```
...
three/examples/jsm/lines/Line2.js (guessing 'Line2_js')
three/examples/jsm/lines/LineMaterial.js (guessing 'LineMaterial_js')
three/examples/jsm/lines/LineGeometry.js (guessing 'LineGeometry_js')
three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls (guessing 'OrbitControls')
@deck.gl/core (guessing 'core')
@deck.gl/layers (guessing 'layers')
(!) Unresolved dependencies
```